# Unable to find ISOWeek

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to use [ISOWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek?view=net-6.0) but I can't find it anywhere. I've tried a few different ways of using it:

```
var a = System.Globalization.ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now);
var b = ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now);
var c = new ISOWeek();
```

I've tried adding every System.Runtime reference I could find, but it's always giving these errors:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ISOWeek' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Globalization' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

> error CS0103: The name 'ISOWeek' does not exist in the current context

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ISOWeek' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.1

How can I get access to ISOWeek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISOWeek` is not in .NET Framework. It is only available in .NET Core 3+, and .NET 5+.